# jquery decompress compressed stream zlib

Tags: jquery, flask, compression

I am using a flask application to stream some html markup data to client browser. I want to compress and send the data stream. I could use the compression at the server end (zlib compression) but unfortunately, I am not finding a way to decompress it at the client end (using jquery). Because of this issue, I am getting garbage display in the browser as below.

```
eJw=��[�۶���+���At�����(�m6�EѶl]hR�^~��l�Z^K֐3)�"��OÙ�ef(�s˲R�\�~8�--�?�i��ݪB���us��3%�lj]��ӿ�n���/?}nׂ�_>������[���W�?u�?�P��g�fJ|�Y%N�>���Ӊ�� �Y����y�m?���>?^�M�TZ�����o�Y^�/��=��) y���u
X!�e
```

The original data (as depicted in : html_result_file) below should be as follows :

```
<table id="table_id" class="striped hoverable responsive-table centered">
<thead><tr><th>Cluster</th><th>vserver</th><th>share-name</th></tr></thead>
<tr><td>ct-cis-cldd-x01</td><td>av-cisdd01-ct01</td><td>admin$</td></tr>
<tr><td>ct-cis-cldd-x01</td><td>av-cisdd01-ct01</td><td>c$</td></tr>`enter code here`
<tr><td>ct-cis-cldd-x01</td><td>av-cisdd01-ct01</td><td>ipc$</td></tr>
</table>
```

My flask application code is as below :

```
        import zlib
        compressor = zlib.compressobj()

        def generate():
             with open (html_result_file,'r') as fr:
                for line in fr:
                    yield compressor.compress(line.encode())

            yield compressor.flush()
        
        response = Response(generate(), mimetype='application/zlib')
    return response
```

My jquery code receiving this response is as below...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12" id="tabdata">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
            $.ajax({
            type: $('#testform').attr('method'),
            url: $('#testform').attr('action'),
            data: $('#testform').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response) 
                $('#tabdata').html(response)
</script>
```

Here, the console.log statement displays the garbage values received from the application.

It would be great if some one could suggest a way to decompress this response correctly for displaying on the browser.

My main aim is to achieve compression here while sending the stream and I am happy to achieve it any alternate ways..

Comment: Any response for this?

Comment: Please don't copy and paste failed attempts at printing binary data. The question marks in hexagons are data that could not be printed, and so cannot be deduced from what you posted. We can't help you given that gobbledygook. You need to convert binary data to either Base64 or hexadecimal for inclusion in questions.

Comment: Hello mark. The original data should be like : <table id="table_id" class="striped hoverable responsive-table centered">
<thead><tr><th>Cluster</th><th>vserver</th><th>share-name</th></tr></thead>
<tr><td>ct-cis-cldd-x01</td><td>av-cisdd01-ct01</td><td>admin$</td></tr>
<tr><td>ct-cis-cldd-x01</td><td>av-cisdd01-ct01</td><td>c$</td></tr>
<tr><td>ct-cis-cldd-x01</td><td>av-cisdd01-ct01</td><td>ipc$</td></tr>
</table>   ....  I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You're not understanding.

Comment: Can you suggest a decompression algorithm at client side to read zlib compressed data. That is what the concern is....

Comment: I can't help until I can see the data you're trying to decompress. It's what you're calling "garbage" that I'd need to see a base64 or hexadecimal representation of.

Comment: Hi mark. Base 64 encoded value is this :  b'PHRhYmxlIGlkPSJ0YWJsZV9pZCIgY2xhc3M9InN0cmlwZWQgaG92ZXJhYmxlIHJlc3BvbnNpdmUtdGFibGUgY2VudGVyZWQiPiAgICAgICAgICAgICA8dGhlYWQ+PHRyPjx0aD5DbHVzdGVyPC90aD48dGg+dnNlcnZlcjwvdGg+PHRoPnNoYXJlLW5hbWU8L3RoPjwvdHI+PC90aGVhZD4gICAgICAgICAgICAgPHRyPjx0ZD5jdC1jaXMtY2xkZC14MDE8L3RkPjx0ZD5hdi1jaXNkZDAxLWN0MDE8L3RkPjx0ZD5hZG1pbiQ8L3RkPjwvdHI+ICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvdGFibGU+'

Comment: That is not the compressed data that you are showing as garbage.

Comment: Leave it. Thanks for looking into this!!!